# R DT:datatable remove .no-footer border-bottom

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, dt

Trying to remove the footer border from a DT:datatable in R.

Looking at this [datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSofA.png), I found the following code to eliminate the border (indicated in red) between the column names (which are empty "") and the data:

```
  headerCallback <- c(
    "function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
    "  $('th', thead).css('border-bottom', 'none');",
    "}"
  ),
```

```
DT::datatable(
      data = myData(),
      class = "compact",
      rownames = FALSE,
      colnames = c("",""),
      caption = tags$caption(myTitle, style = "color:black"),
      options = list(
        dom = 't',
        ordering = FALSE,
        paging = FALSE,
        searching = FALSE,
        headerCallback = JS(headerCallback)
      )
    )

  })
```

What I'm trying to do is now eliminate the bottom black line in the image. I found the following links that seem to be what I'm looking for, but now sure how to incorporate them into what I have:

[r - How to remove the horizontal line between the header and the body in a DT::datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533474/r-how-to-remove-the-horizontal-line-between-the-header-and-the-body-in-a-dtd)

[How To Remove Black Lines](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32819/how-to-remove-black-lines)

When I inspect the element on the webpage, and expand `<table>` I can un-check [this box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdWew.png) which removes the bottom black line and gives me what I want. However, not sure how to write that into my existing or a new callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
datatable(
  data = iris[1:5,1:2],
  class = "compact",
  rownames = FALSE,
  colnames = c("",""),
  callback = JS("$('table.dataTable.no-footer').css('border-bottom', 'none');"),
  options = list(
    dom = 't',
    ordering = FALSE,
    paging = FALSE,
    searching = FALSE,
    headerCallback = JS(headerCallback)
  )
)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! So if I want to add ```table.dataTable thead td``` to that same line, how would I do that?

Comment: @Mr.Norris Could you try `JS("$('table.dataTable.no-footer,table.dataTable thead td').css('border-bottom', 'none');")`.

Comment: Brilliant! Yes, that worked as well. I did change ```td``` to ```th```.
This also worked:
```callback = JS(c("$('table.dataTable thead th').css('border-bottom', 'none');",
                      "$('table.dataTable.no-footer').css('border-bottom', 'none');")),```
Thank you!