# How to correct header alignment and footer border on DT datatable for R Shiny app

Tags: css, r, shiny, datatable, dt

I have created a DT datatable that works, but is currently looking like this:

[image]

I would like to: 1) align the header row with the table content and 2) and remove the horizontal line at the bottom of the table.

I have tried the solution to remove the horizontal line: [R DT:datatable remove .no-footer border-bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630958/r-dtdatatable-remove-no-footer-border-bottom) but it results in the table not displaying.

How do I do this?

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
column_names <- c(toupper(letters[1:26]),tolower(letters[1:26]))
df <- data.frame(replicate(length(column_names),sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))

# assign column names
colnames(df) = column_names


ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(
    "column_selection",
    h3("Select fields to display"),
    choices = column_names,
    inline = TRUE,
    selected = c('A','B','C')
  ),
  DT::dataTableOutput("alphabet")
)

  
  

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$alphabet <- DT::renderDT({
    columns = column_names
    if (!is.null(input$column_selection)) {
      columns = input$column_selection
    }
    datatable(
      df[, columns, drop = FALSE],
      rownames = FALSE,
      class = "row-border hover stripe",
      extensions = c('Buttons'),
      options = list(
        # change colour of header row
        initComplete = JS(
          "function(settings, json) {",
          "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': 'black', 'color': 'white'});",
          "}"),
        dom = 'Brtip',
        autoWidth = T,
        scrollX = T,
        buttons = list(c('copy', 'csv', 'excel'))
      )
    )
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Removing autoWidth = T, should resolve your column alignment